# Fade between multiple images from same URL without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, css

By cobbling together bits and pieces of various other answers from SO and elsewhere I have something that almost does what I want, but not quite:

- I have to reload the page to get a new image.
- Each new image fades in, but the previous image cuts out instantly rather fading across

Clicking on the image skips to the next one the same way.

The url I'm using returns a different image each time the server receives a request. I can change the URL to something else and it will still work. Is there a way to fade smoothly between images served in this way without refreshing the page? The other solutions I've found for this involve specifying a list of images somewhere in the page and rotating through them, which doesn't seem to work when every image has the same url.

I am trying to do this using only html + css + js.

```
<html>
   <head>
      
      <script type = "text/JavaScript">
         <!--
            function AutoRefresh( t ) {
               setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
            }
         //-->
      </script>
      
      <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
      
        .fade-in{
          -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s ease;
          -moz-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
          -ms-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
          -o-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
          animation: fade-in 2s ease;
          visibility: visible;
          -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100vh;
            margin: auto;         
        }
        
        .imgbox {
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
        }       

        @-webkit-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}
        @-moz-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
        @-o-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
        @keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}     
      </style>
      
   </head>
   
   <body onload = "JavaScript:AutoRefresh(10000);">
    <div class="imgbox">
    <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">
        <img class = "fade-in" src="http://192.168.1.151:6600" style="object-fit:contain;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;" />
    </a>
    </div>
   </body>
   
   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible to use just JS/CSS/HTML to fade in and out between images without needing to reload the page.

To fade in and out between two images you'll need to have them both loaded. But in this case we cannot have two img elements with the same URL as the browser would assume the images were the same and therefore not ask the server for another one.

We get round this by adding a random query string to the end of the URL each time to persuade the browser to get another img. I'm using picsum and using their way of doing this, the method may differ for your service, though normally adding a random query to a URL doesn't upset the server, and it's only the browser we need to convince to send another request.

We load a new img with `opacity: 0` so there isn't a sudden jump, and then we gradually fade it in while fading the other one out using your animation.

I have put the inline img styling into the head to tidy things up as we now have two images. I've removed the system-dependent prefixes just to make things easier to read, but of course put them back if you need them.

UPDATE: there was an additional requirement to not send requests to the image server too often. A pause flag has been added to indicate we cannot respond to the user's click which is unset after 2 seconds.

```js
const imgs = [document.getElementById('img1'),document.getElementById('img2')];
    
  let back=0; //0 or 1 depending on which img is faded out
  let pause = false; //a flag to say it's too soon to get another image
    
    let randomiser = 1;//we add this to the end of the img src to persuade the browser it really does need to get another image from the image server
 
  function imgLoaded() {
  
    imgs[back].style.animationDirection = 'normal';// will now fade in
    
    back = (back + 1)%2;//make the other img the back
    imgs[back].style.animationDirection = 'reverse'; // will now fade out 
    
      imgs[0].style.animationName = 'fade-in';
    imgs[1].style.animationName = 'fade-in';
    }
    
    function next() { 
    if (pause) { return; }
      imgs[0].style.animationName ='nothing';
    imgs[1].style.animationName = 'nothing';
    imgs[back].style.opacity = 0;// these should already be there, but just in case animation still on the go
    imgs[(back+1)%2].style.opacity = 1;
    randomiser++;
    imgs[back].src = 'https://picsum.photos/1024/768.jpg?random='+ randomiser;     
    pause = true;
    setTimeout(function () { pause = false; },2000);//dont ask for another image until 2 seconds is up
  }
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        body {
           width:100vw;
           height: 100vh;
        }
      
        
        .imgbox {
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
        }       

        @keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
        
        @keyframes nothing {}
        
        .imgbox img {
          object-fit:contain;
          display:block;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
          position: absolute;
          opacity:0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;         
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
```

```html
<div class="imgbox" onclick="next();">
        <img id="img1" onload="imgLoaded();" src="https://picsum.photos/1024/768.jpg?random=0"/>
        <img id="img2" onload="imgLoaded();" src="https://picsum.photos/1024/768.jpg?random=0"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you - this answers the question as posted. Is there a way to combine this with lazy  loading of the images? The server I'm using returns an error if it receives more than 1 request every 2 seconds.

Comment: Timer added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again - however, there still seems to be a problem loading the first two images - I think even though one is faded out, the browser tries to load both simultaneously during the initial page load. I expect your solution works for subsequent loads.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do at the start. Do you want an image to be there already and not faded, or do you want a space with just a message telling the user they can click to see images, or... I left it with two images because I didnt know what you wanted and it sort of gave the user the idea of pictures changing. Anyway, not difficult to change the start.

Comment: I was aiming for one image to be visible on the initial page load. Is there a simple way to tell the browser not to try to load the second image as soon as the page loads?

Comment: Asking the server to serve the same image is the simplest way of doing this. But if depends on how you can get your image server to do this. On picsum sending the same random query setting serves the same image. See altered snippet. If this doesn't work with your server you need to do something like adding a bit of code to load an image and not add the fade animation the first time.

Comment: I was just missing one last point - if the html and js are in the same file, the script has to go below the body, otherwise it can't reference the images by their IDs. Thanks again - now working correctly!